# Can one add a small amount of text that "breaks" the align environment?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I would like to know whether there's any way to include some text **in one of the lines** of some aligned output but that exists "outside" of the alignment. (In case it makes a difference, I am asking this about a document I'm writing in Overleaf.) Here a sample code:

```
\begin{enumerate
\item \-\hspace{4cm} $\tan^{-1} x + tan^{-1} y = \frac{\pi}{4} \Longleftrightarrow (x+1)(y+1) = 2$
Proof:
\begin{align*}
\tan^{-1}x + tan^{-1}y = \frac{\pi}{4} & \Longleftrightarrow \tan \left(\tan^{-1}x + tan^{-1}y\right) = 1 \\[2mm]
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x+y}{1-xy} = 1 \\[2mm]
& \Longleftrightarrow (x+1)(y+1) = 2
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}}
```

This yields the following output:

[image: align I]

I would like to have the word "Proof" be part of the first line of the proof but not be affected by the align environment. I tried including the "Proof" in the first line with it's own set of &'s, but that indented the word much more than I liked:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \-\hspace{4cm} $\tan^{-1}x + tan^{-1}y = \frac{\pi}{4} \Longleftrightarrow (x+1)(y+1) = 2$
\begin{align*}
&\text{Proof:}&\tan^{-1}x+tan^{-1}y=\frac{\pi}{4}&\Longleftrightarrow\tan\left(\tan^{-1}x+tan^{-1}y\right)=1\\[2mm]
&&& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x+y}{1-xy} = 1 \\[2mm]
&&& \Longleftrightarrow (x+1)(y+1) = 2
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image: align II]

Ideally I'd like the "Proof" to be as far left as it is in the first image, just a bit to the right of the number 1, but still part of the first line as in the second image. If that's possible, perhaps I could also align the top line with the first line of the proof without having to push it to the right separately with the -\hspace as I did.

I did search the site for answers, the closest thing I found to what I want is \intertext, but that adds a separate line outside the \align environment; is there something similar that I can use but that puts the text in one of the lines that's aligned?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The statement you’re trying to prove is false without the assumption that *x* > -1 and *y* > -1. Very common mistake that you don’t want to tell your students.

Comment: See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qtjtr4swmw to see why.

Comment: @egreg I appreciate the heads up; I did know the two factors on the right needed to be positive, but I very possibly might have forgotten to make a note of that had you not brought it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you employ an `aligned` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}y = \tfrac{1}{4}\pi 
      \Longleftrightarrow (x+1)(y+1) = 2$.

\medskip
Proof.\quad
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
    \tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}y = \tfrac{1}{4}\pi 
      &\Longleftrightarrow \tan(\tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}y) = 1 \\
      &\Longleftrightarrow \frac{x+y}{1-xy} = 1 \\
      &\Longleftrightarrow (x+1)(y+1) = 2\,.
    \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked great. May I ask what the [t] does? I tried removing it and the "Proof" ended up at the beginning of the second line rather than the first.

Comment: It aligns the environment at the top. You will understand it if you replace `t` (top) by `c` (center) and `b` (bottom) for a second.

Comment: @Οὖτις Yes, got it, I guess by leaving out the [t] completely it defaulted to [c] which is why the "Proof" ended up with the middle line. Is there a name for these? I'd like to find out a little more about what they do and whether they can be used in other environments.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it is simply called (vertical) alignment.